# How to render map tiles in a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, gis

I have implemented a custom UIView that loads a list of tiles and now I want to render those tiles. However, I have no idea how to implement it inside a UIView efficiently. The tiles are in PNG format. Should I use CALayers to implement them?

EDIT: I want to clarify more details about my project. I have built my own Maps framework that fetches tiles from a tile server of any kind based on the given coordinates. For example, at coordinate (50.5, 30.51) the app generates the following URLs:

```
http://b.tile.osm.org/15/19159/11040.png
http://c.tile.osm.org/15/19159/11041.png
http://a.tile.osm.org/15/19159/11042.png
http://b.tile.osm.org/15/19159/11043.png
http://c.tile.osm.org/15/19160/11040.png
http://a.tile.osm.org/15/19160/11041.png
http://b.tile.osm.org/15/19160/11042.png
http://c.tile.osm.org/15/19160/11043.png
http://a.tile.osm.org/15/19161/11040.png
http://b.tile.osm.org/15/19161/11041.png
http://c.tile.osm.org/15/19161/11042.png
http://a.tile.osm.org/15/19161/11043.png
http://b.tile.osm.org/15/19162/11040.png
http://c.tile.osm.org/15/19162/11041.png
http://a.tile.osm.org/15/19162/11042.png
http://b.tile.osm.org/15/19162/11043.png
```

Using UIImageView wouldn't work because I need to fetch and display all the tiles.

Comment: are you talking about drawing overlays on top of maps??

Comment: You can use CALayers but why not UIImageView?

Comment: @satheeshwaran No, I build my own maps library.

Comment: @tmpz because there are multiple tiles. I'll edit my question for more details

Comment: You should use a UIScrollView, I have done the same for rendering PDF's using a UIScrollview

Comment: I agree with @satheeshwaran, use a scrollview and a uiimageview for each tile